# How to read messages in flight status and delete it by boto library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

For testing purpose, I need to read the messages in flight and delete the messages in flight. I can't find a suitable solution so I use work around way now

to read messages in flight
 1. stop message consumer process
 2. wait for message is available and read it but not delete 
 3. start message consumer process

to delete message in flight (try clear() but it only delete message available)
 1. delete queue
 2. recreate queue

Any better solution?

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to do this ?  It looks like you're trying to work against SQS design and all your proposed workaround are heavyweight.

Comment: You can not delete a queue to delete one message. You would loose all the other messages waiting and would cause error in other message producers / consumers apps based on this queue. It is like deleting a database to delete a single record

Comment: Do you have a correct understanding of the definition of messages in flight?  They are messages your consumer has already received, but SQS has not seen any subsequent valid requests from your consumer to delete them or otherwise modify their visibility.  They are *inaccessible by design*.

Answer (score 4):

You can't view or delete messages in flight, unless you delete/view them from the consumer to whom they are currently 'in flight' to.

Messages become 'in flight' when a consumer requests them, so if you want to delete the message, you can, as long as its the same consumer that requested the message in the first place.

Its not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish, if you gave a better explanation of the ultimate goal, perhaps someone could suggest a better solution.

BTW, you no longer need to delete a queue if you want to delete the messages in a queue all at once - there is a new 'purge queue' option just released in the last month or so - if that helps with your solution

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/purge-queue.html

Comment: My ultimate goal is my test script need to verify message in sqs is correct. But before I can read it to verify, maybe it's already read by consumer.  So my question is that if unfortunately it's already read by consumer and become in flight, may my test script still read it for verification purpose. As for delete message in in flight mode, it's because I need to make sure sqs is clean in unit test setup function.

Comment: If you need to verify a stream of messages, consider using SNS to fanout identical messages streams to dual queues - one queue that is used exclusively for testing/verification, the other that is used by the actual consumer.